# Summing different conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to develop an aggregate score based on a number of factors across approximately 15 columns.

For instance:

```
Col. A = 12; Col. B = Y; Col. C = Green; Col. D = 3
```

Column E should have a formula that gives an aggregate score:

> Under Column A, if the number is between 0-5, that is worth 0.1, if 6-10, that is worth 0.3, if 11 - X, that is 0.5
>
> Under Column B, if Y then 1, if N then 0
>
> Under Column C, if Green then 0, if Yellow then 1, if Red then 2
>
> Under Column D, if 0-3 then 5, if 4-8 then 6, if 9-17 then 7

That means my formula in Column E should return `0.3+1+0+5` or `6.3`

I've tried the following formula:

```
=SUM((IF(B2>=0&B2<=3,0.1),IF(B2>=4&B2<=7,0.3),IF(B2>=8,0.5)), C2)
```

But this has led to `#VALUE` errors

Comment: You could maybe use a vlookup table or an If statement.  You mention getting `#VALUE` errors with your formula, can you post your formula please?

Comment: `Under Column D, if 0-3 then 5, if 4-8 then 6 etc etc.` We're supposed to read your mind on the `etc`?

Comment: As you will tell I'm no expert, but was starting to go with:

Comment: Can you [*please*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post what you have tried? Also, @findwindow was asking how we would know what the "etc. etc." is.  You don't have to be an expert to answer that. So if D is 9-13, return 7?

Comment: For Column D, I wanted to give an idea what I was aiming for, the values for the different ranges would depend on the raw number provided, but to clarify it could conceivably go if 9-12 then 7, if 13-40, then 8, if 41-1Billion then 10. It doesn't really matter what the ranges are, the point would be that the formula recognizes the range and assigns a corresponding value

Comment: Sorry, my comment cut out. I started with: SUM((IF(B2>=0&B2<=3,0.1),IF(B2>=4&B2<=7,0.3),IF(B2>=8,0.5)), C2); So for instance under B2, I have 6, and under C2 I have 5, therefore the value under D2 should be 0.3 + 5, 5.3

Comment: @premiumcopypaper - can you add these comments to your OP? Especially the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made some assumptions that need tweaking. Here is a corrected version of the formula you've supplied:

```
=SUM((IF(AND(B2>=0,B2<=3),0.1,IF(AND(B2>=4, B2<=7),0.3,IF(B2>=8,0.5,0)))), C2)
```

You'll notice that instead of using the "&" operator, it uses a new function, the AND() function, to evaluate multiple conditions. This is standard in Excel formulas, the "&" operator is used to concatenate strings. Secondly, the corrected statement uses *nested if statements*, which you can google to get more information on. Basically, the False portion of the if statement is another if statement - this makes it so that your second if statement gets evaluated only if the first if statement fails its conditional test and is false.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. I will give it a try. In the above example we're only drawing from 2 columns, but your above formula should be expandable to about 15 different criteria correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be arbitrarily long.